# Windows Phone 7.1 WebClient POST without body

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to Web service calls; I can do simple GET and parse the JSON output. Not good with POST and especially if the URI has spaces and quotes.

I am trying to send the following URI to the server in Windows Phone 7.1 (Emulator). It says "Not found error". This error seems to be generic; it doesn't say what's really was wrong anyway.

https://aaabbb.com//services/v4/put/users/xxxxx/device?deviceId=2NDJDRkI5MEVFME -H 'Access: Token token=CXJTY'

There is no JSON body/data for this. It just this URL with the shown params. thats where data is too.

how do I do this with WebClient class or RestSharp? I tried this using WebClient class in WP 7. didn't succeed. So downloaded RestSharp; but not sure how the above URI without any JSON data could be sent.

I followed some of the posts in here to use the WeClient class. It didn't work.

Comment: The url you posted is not valid. You can't have spaces in it.

Comment: The URL doesn't have spaces init. Its the parameters; I thought the parameters can have space or quotes or other chars. It needs to be translated/encoded. Assuming there is no space how is it done. Its kind of two questions. Thanks.

Comment: You need to either encode the parameter portion of the url with Uri.EscapeDataString or encode the entire url with Uri.EscapeUrlString.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **URL-encode** your string. For that, you can do something like this:

```
string deviceId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("2NDJDRkI5MEVFME -H 'Access: Token token=CXJTY'");
Uri uri = new Uri("https://aaabbb.com/services/v4/put/users/xxxxx/device");
string data = "deviceId=" + deviceID;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, data);
wc.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadComplete;
```